# how to use ldapmodifyuser from ldapscripts to change a value

Tags: openldap

I can't find an example of how to use the [ldapscripts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/ldapmodifyuser.1.html) command `ldapmodifyuser` and I'm not familiar enough with `ldapmodify` to figure it out.

For example, how can I use `ldapmodifyuser` to change a user's `givenName`?

Here's my attempt:

```
~$ sudo ldapmodifyuser 9928892
# About to modify the following entry :
dn: uid=9928892,ou=Users,dc=thisplace,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: 9928892
sn: FUJI
givenName: GABUTO
cn: GABUTO FUJISHITA
displayName: GABUTO FUJISHITA
uidNumber: 18055
gidNumber: 5000
gecos: GABUTO FUJISHITA
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/9928892
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fS...
shadowLastChange: 17575

# Enter your modifications here, end with CTRL-D.
dn: uid=9928892,ou=Users,dc=thisplace,dc=com
givenName:GAKUTO      # Ctrl+D
Error modifying user entry uid=9928892,ou=Users,dc=thisplace,dc=com in LDAP
```

Comment: Did you hit Ctrl+D on the same line as the givenName text?

Comment: Tried both, same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify

```
changetype: modify
```

and

```
replace: givenName
```

It should have been:

```
sudo ldapmodifyuser 9928892
# About to modify the following entry :
dn: uid=9928892,ou=Users,dc=thisplace,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: 9928892
sn: FUJI
givenName: GABUTO
cn: GABUTO FUJISHITA
displayName: GABUTO FUJISHITA
uidNumber: 18055
gidNumber: 5000
gecos: GABUTO FUJISHITA
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/9928892
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fS...
shadowLastChange: 17575

# Enter your modifications here, end with CTRL-D.
dn: uid=9928892,ou=Users,dc=thisplace,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: givenName
givenName:GAKUTO      # Ctrl+D
```